# how to count records in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new in mongodb.
i have a simple email Schema which implemented like below :

```
const emailSchema = new Schema({
  from:{
    type: String
  },
  to: {
    type: String
  },
  subject: {
    type: String
  },
  content: {
    type: String
  },
  provider:{
    type: String
  },
  success:{
    type: Boolean
  }
```

now i want to query all email records and seprate them in two array. one for `provider=x` and `provider = y` . then count each one's `success` field.
how can i write such query ?

Comment: What have you tried? Show an attempt and your expected output. This at least makes it clearer as to what result you actually expect and shows some respect that this is not a code writing service. People are happy to help, but less happy to do your job for you.

Comment: `db.email.find( { provider: { $eq: 'x' } } ).count()`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to count success: true for any provider

```
emailSchema.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    { 'success': true }
  },
  $group: {
    _id: {
      provider: '$provider'
    }, //group by provider 
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  } //sum of success fields
]);
```

If you only want to count success field exists or not it may be true or false for any provider

```
emailSchema.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    {'success': { $exists: true }}
  },
  $group: {
    _id: {
      provider: '$provider'
    }, //group by provider 
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  } //sum of success fields
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregate query for group and count

```
emailSchema.aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: {
          provider: '$provider'
        }, //group by provider 
        count: {
          $sum: '$success'
        }
      } //sum of success fields
    ])
```